# Search requires data from multiple cursors/tables

Tags: android, sqlite, search, cursor

I'm still trying to implement a search function into my Android app. So far it's going ok, although currently the search can only query one table and display the results for this table (its a ListView using SimpleCursorAdapter).

What I want is to be able to search multiple tables, but I'm not sure how to get this all into one cursor or extend the SimpleCursorAdapter to implement multiple cursors. I see there is a class called CursorJoiner, but I'm not sure what I need to do with it.

Thanks!

I have tried to make a custom cursor[] adapter, but this doesn't return anything and my search results are blank- can anyone help?

```
public class SearchCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

private int currentCursor;
private int curPosition = 0;
private int total = 0;
private Cursor[] curs = null;
private Context cont;

public SearchCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
        String[] from, int[] to) {

    super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    total = c.getCount();

}

public SearchCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor[] c,
        String[] from, int[] to) {

    super(context, layout, null, from, to);
    int l = c.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {

        total += c[i].getCount();

    }
    curs = c;
    currentCursor = 0;
    cont = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (currentCursor == curs.length)
        return null;

    if (curs == null) {

        //normal shiz

    }
    else {

        Cursor c = curs[currentCursor];
        c.moveToPosition(curPosition);

        if (c.isAfterLast()) {

            currentCursor++;
            c = curs[currentCursor];
            curPosition = 0;
            c.moveToPosition(curPosition);

        }

        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = vi.inflate(R.layout.search_row, null);
        }

        TextView t1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.rowitem_text1);
        TextView t2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.rowitem_text2);

        t1.setText(c.getString(1));
        t2.setText("Testing");

        curPosition++;

    }

    return view;
```

just noticed that it's not actually the adapter returning nothing, there's something wrong with my searchactivity...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I want is to be able to search
>   multiple tables, but I'm not sure how
>   to get this all into one cursor or
>   extend the SimpleCursorAdapter to
>   implement multiple cursors

If you are using SQLite, implement a `JOIN` in your `SELECT` statement. If you have wrapped SQLite in a content provider for some reason, expose another content `Uri` and support for your multi-table search.

Comment: Erm... how? Sorry, I'm really inexperienced with SQL. I read a little bit about it but it seems like there must be some relationship between the tables, which in my case there isn't- they're both just lists of values. I've tried to make a custom cursor/arrayadapter (see edit above) but that just returns nothing.

Comment: @Espiandev: Sorry, "search multiple tables" can have many definitions, and I guessed the wrong one. In your case, if I now understand it correctly, use `MergeCursor` (in SDK) or my `MergeAdapter`, depending on whether or not the rows should look different between the multiple tables you're searching. http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge

Comment: Hi i i have applied join on now two tables one the column that is primary key in `First` table is foreign in the `Second` table. Second table have 3 rows associated with the `Foreign key` i have managed to query but don't know how to read the cursor let say having 1 row from first table and 3 rows from the second table in one query.